# call external function in vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want use jsgrid.min.js to create table in vue component.I should call this in jsgrid.min.jsfunction

```
jsGrid(..)
```

how can i do this?(call a function that placed outer the vue component in component )

component.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="jsGrid">

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
        name: "mja"
    }),


    mounted () {

        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            width: "100%",
            height: "500px"

            });

    }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

error

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).jsGrid is not a function"

I actually embedded src file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('plugins/jsgrid/dist/jsgrid.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: I think this [codepen](https://codepen.io/randyyaj/pen/JbBKBa) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need To Include Jquery as jsGrid using Jquery , Here is Working Demo :)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted:function(){
        jQuery("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",
        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        data: this.clients,
        fields: [
            { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
            { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
            { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
            { name: "Country", type: "select", items: this.countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
            { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
            { type: "control" }
        ]
    });
  },
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue App!',
    clients : [
        { "Name": "Otto Clay", "Age": 25, "Country": 1, "Address": "Ap #897-1459 Quam Avenue", "Married": false },
        { "Name": "Connor Johnston", "Age": 45, "Country": 2, "Address": "Ap #370-4647 Dis Av.", "Married": true },
        { "Name": "Lacey Hess", "Age": 29, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #365-8835 Integer St.", "Married": false },
        { "Name": "Timothy Henson", "Age": 56, "Country": 1, "Address": "911-5143 Luctus Ave", "Married": true },
        { "Name": "Ramona Benton", "Age": 32, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #614-689 Vehicula Street", "Married": false }
    ],
    countries :[
        { Name: "", Id: 0 },
        { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
        { Name: "Canada", Id: 2 },
        { Name: "United Kingdom", Id: 3 }
    ],
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
 {{ message }}
<div id="jsGrid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how I convert it to component ?. if I use component i will have Previous error!